# How to turn a pandas column of seconds as float values into time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with a column like this:

```
df
```

| time |
| --- |
| 0.5 |
| 30.5 |
| 60.3 |
| 90.2 |
| 120.3 |

and so on, with each time represented as a float of seconds - for example, 60.3 is simply 60.3 seconds. How can I turn this into data type of time? I have tried:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

but it is returning incorrect values. For example, time of 60.3 seconds is converted into:

```
0 days 00:00:00.000000060
```

which is not only incorrect as it should be 0 days 00:00:60.3, but I would also like to only extract the minutes and seconds, leaving with me a column of data that looks like:

```
00:60.3
```

Thank you.

Comment: Default unit for [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) is nanoseconds. If these are seconds change the unit -> `df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='s')`

Comment: Are you looking to modify how the timedelta is displayed? Or actually reduce the values to a string? Because extracting just the hours, minutes, and seconds will make it a string no longer capable of datetime-like operations.

Comment: @HenryEcker thank you! Changing the unit worked and I did not realize modifying it would make date time operations ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use .to_datetime and set the unit to seconds ('s'). Then you can apply a format to the datetime object.

Try this out:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit='s').apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%M:%S.%f"))
```

Should get:

```
           time
0  00:00.500000
1  00:30.500000
2  01:00.300000
3  01:30.200000
4  02:00.300000
```